# Deploying python wheel package in private github repo

Tags: python, github, installation, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to deploy private python package, however I would like build it once locally and avoid rebuilding while installing.

In details, my package has setup.py and required config files, after building it locally it puts the .whl file into dist directory.

simplified directory structure looks like:

```
root
|
|-> setup.py
|-> my_package.cpp [compiled extension]
|-> CMakeLists.txt 
|-> dist
    |-> my_wheel_package.whl
```

As I can get package with:

```
pip install git+my_git_repo
```

**I wanted to use something like:**

```
pip isntall git+my_git_repo/dist/my_wheel_package.whl
```

but this doesn't work, as pip is always trying to find setup.py. (which is not visible form dist directory)

I dont want to use https "url" option, as it requires to get github token. Many people has already access to this git repo, so I wanted avoid adding additional steps from user perspective (Therefore I am trying to avoid installation as it requires C extension compilation).

**The outcome I am expecting is to have github repository with .whl package somewhere which can be installed directly with pip without compilation step.**

Comment: Why are you trying to get Git to do what PyPI is for? ("without compilation step" will cause all sorts of trouble - Windows packages don't work on Linux, 64-bit packages don't work on 32-bit, ARM packages don't work on x86, etc - PyPI solves all of that for you, but you'd have to do all that yourself on Git, plus you have to get it to work first, while it's 0 effort on PyPI)

Comment: Yes it is all true, but PyPI is public repository, while I want to keep package private.

Comment: There are several solutions available that allow you to deploy your own PyPI (or compatible) server - have you looked into any of them?

Comment: I am aware of these options, but they are backup plan, but I would like to avoid setting up new infrastructure yet. 

Github with private repos is already accessible by required people, so it is less effort. I am working in well known environment so "without compilation" is not issue (even if it will be github still can be used to compile package as it is usually done).

Comment: If you're providing the package to users that have access to your private repo on GitHub and building the code from source is not an issue, why even bother with wheels? Just include the code in the repo, or set up a Git submodule with the package and build it from there?

Comment: To exactly avoid building.

Comment: Getting built package with wheels via pip from github would be very convenient way to deliver. I understand that you want to convince me to different approach, but I am highly interested in finding solution to posted problem.